# Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x^2e^{-ax^2+bx}) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gaussian-integral

I'm trying to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x^2e^{-ax^2+bx}) dx$. The shape of the integral seems to suggests 2 approaches: Integration by parts and completing the square. However, both approaches don't quite work, there always are $x$ terms that get in the way. For example, trying integration by parts gives:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x^2e^{-ax^2+bx}) dx = [x^2\frac{e^{-ax^2+bx}}{-2ax+b}]|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (2x\frac{e^{-ax^2+bx}}{-2ax+b}) dx$$ And while the first summand goes to zero the second summand is an even nastier integral than the first. I tried completing the square in the exponent, but that too doesn't solve the problem. What's the trick here? How does one crack this integral?

Comment: In fact, completing the square gives an answer. For this direction, you may apply the substitution $x = t+\frac{b}{2a}$. (*Edit.* This corresponds to user284331's computation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-a(x-b/2a)^{2}}e^{b^{2}/4a}dx\\
&=e^{b^{2}/4a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x+b/2a)^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}dx\\
&=e^{b^{2}/4a}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-ax^{2}}dx+\dfrac{b}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-ax^{2}}dx+\dfrac{b^{2}}{4a^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^{2}}dx\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: I see you used a substitution in the first equality.

Comment: Yes, you are right.